# Sending form data in volley post request

Tags: android, django-rest-framework, android-volley, form-data

The postman response is this image:

[image: This is the postman request out of which i a, getting the perfect response]

This is the code i am using to send the data in the post request. Although i am getting a 400 response code from this.

```
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                    API.ADD_PAYMENT,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            onBackPressed();
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(AddPaymentActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                    params.put("amount", "123");
                    params.put("description", "Not Paid");
                    params.put("customer", "1");
                    return params;
                }

                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
                    headers.put("Authorization", "token 0ee1248c5a84e8b1e36a8a15da48c0bb7580926c");
                    return headers;
                }
            };
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(AddPaymentActivity.this);
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: it's my own server, the rest api's are made on django. The auth token is just what i have to attach in the header everytime i make a request.

Comment: yes it is must its kind of an identity of the user that is currently logged in on the app

Comment: no i don't need that. thanks for help but the server side is working because the postman is giving a ok response. it's only the volley which is creaating an issue

Comment: Just remove `headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");` and try in Volley request.

Answer (score 0):

First of all why don't you use `JsonObjectRequest` instead of `StringRequest` when you're using `application/json` as your talking language with server? Second have you tried passing your parameters to the other request constructor like below?

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("amount", 123);
params.put("description", "Not Paid");
params.put("customer", 1);
JsonObjectRequest jor = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, API.ADD_PAYMENT, new JSONObject(params), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
...
```

Passing your headers are essential so the rest of you code remains as it is.